# Regex matching only first character from value

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to regular expression, A line containing following string.

```
color=Blue color; age=23; name=John Doe
```

In this string `color` is the `key` which is equal to some `value`. `Key` with `equal operator` is assign through variable and concatenate with the regex expression. So only thing is left, just match the `value` without `semi colon`. My Approach for this is

```
var target = 'color=Blue color; age=23; name=John Doe';
var pattern = 'color=';
var re = new RegExp(pattern + ".+?",'g'); // i.e color=.+?
console.log(target.match(re));
```

Output:

```
["color=B"]
```

It's matching only one character because `?` makes quantifiers lazy, But if i remove that `lazy quantifier` then it will match whole target string. How can i make pattern useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.`,use `[^;]` without lazy quantifier.

```
var re = new RegExp(pattern + "[^;]+",'g');
```

- `[^;]` Anything except `;`